# Optimizing query with subselect in two tables

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Table `employee` has two columns:

- **ID**
- **NAME**

Table `external_job` also has two columns:

- **ID**
- **SALARY**

I have to get one person who got the maximum salary.
The result must have three columns and one row:

- **ID**
- **NAME**
- **SALARY**

I made a query but the client asked me not to use a sub-select query.

How can I do in this case?

My query is:

```sql
select *
  from (select a.id,
               a.name,
               (select sum(salary)
                  from external_job b
                 where b.id = a.id) salary
          from employee a
         order by salary desc)
 where rownum = 1
```

Comment: By backend to display the front-end, you mean the browser will first request go api server that will pipe forward request to next.js server and send response to browser?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by` and some method for limiting the results to one row.  In standard SQL this is:

```
select ej.id, e.name, ej.salary
from employee e join
     external_job ej
     on ej.id = e.id
order by ej.salary
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support `fetch first`.  Some use `limit` or `select top` or even more arcane constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption is ID is primary key on both sides.

```
 select  ID, NAME, SALARY from employee e ,  external_job a where e.id= a.id 
 order by salary desc
 limit 1
```